# How do i get common follower for two brands in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have data in this format:

```
 user_name,       name,               TargetBrandName
 Rabiumuhdsanib1, Rabiu muhd sani bkd,GloCare
 KING_habILA,     #KING_BILA JNR,     GloCare
 Habila Ishaku,   NA,                 airtel_care
 Rabiumuhdsanib1, Rabiu muhd sani bkd,
 KING_habILA,     #KING_BILA JNR,     airtel_care
```

The same user_name,name combination can have more than one TargetBrandName.
I need to connect all the user_name to TargetBrandName
e.g..

```
(user_name,name)-[:FOLLOW]->TargetBrandName
```

My aim is to get all the common followers of two brands (say GloCare and airtel_care).

How do i achieve this in neo4j?

Comment: are `user_name` and `name` 1:1? That is, one `user_name` has one `name` ?

Comment: yes..user_name and name are 1:1

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for multiple people who follow a given pair of brand names, I'd think something like this would suffice (and I'm throwing in some labels for clarity):

```
match (b1:Brand {TargetBrandName: 'GloCare'})<-[:FOLLOW]-(u:User)-[:FOLLOW]->(b2:Brand {TargetBrandName: 'airtel_care'})
return u
```

In fact, if you don't care about returning the brand info (since you embedded it in your query already), you can leave off those variables:

```
match (:Brand {TargetBrandName: 'GloCare'})<-[:FOLLOW]-(u:User)-[:FOLLOW]->(:Brand {TargetBrandName: 'airtel_care'})
return u
```

Comment: It returns 'no rows'.
Problem is It does not detect `user` with same `user_name,name` as a single node.